# Why they are subtracting $(-\sin(t/2),-\cos(t/2))$ on MIT calc III problem set.

Tags: calculus, geometry, multivariable-calculus, trigonometry, cycloid

Good day, so the question is from the MIT open courseware page and comes from [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-02sc-multivariable-calculus-fall-2010/1.-vectors-and-matrices/part-c-parametric-equations-for-curves/problem-set-3) which is the "problem set 3". The problem that I don't understand is as follows:

A circular disk of radius 2 has a dot marked at a point halfway between the center
and the circumference. Denote this point by $P$. Suppose that the disk is tangent to
the $x$-axis with the center initially at $(0, 2)$ and P initially at $(0, 1)$, and that it starts
to roll to the right on the x-axis at unit speed. Let C be the curve traced out by the
point P.

b) Use vectors to find the parametric equations for $\vec{OP}$ as a function of time $t$.

The provided solution claims that there is a graph, however, I don't see one. From the mentioned answer, I read the following:
(b) To get to the point $P$, start at the origin, add the vector $(0, 2)$ to go
up to the center of the disk at $t = 0$; then add the vector $(t, 0)$ to get to the
center of the disk at time t; and finally (do what it takes to) shift over by one
unit at an angle $θ = t/2$, measured clockwise from the vertical (see below).
How to do that last move? Just add the vector $−(\sin(t/2), \cos(t/2))$, as can
be seen from a sketch. [note. there is no sketch].
Combining, we get $\vec{OP}(t) = (0, 2) + (t, 0) +( − \sin(t/2), − \cos(t/2))$ or
$r = r(t) = (t − \sin(t/2), 2 − \cos(t/2))$.

Everything else being clear I just do not see how subtracting $(−\sin(t/2),−\cos(t/2))$ would do the job.

Comment: Please use hyper links.

Comment: You have one at the beginning, the problem in question is the first problem from “problem set 3” and the solution is the solution given on exactly the same webpage

Comment: Sorry I meant to contract it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your sketch:

[image]

Initially the center of the circle is at $A(0,2)$ and the dot is at $P(0,1),$
as shown in the circle at the left.
Note that the coordinates of these points imply the coordinates of the vector $\vec{AP} = \langle 0,-1 \rangle.$

Now we roll the circle along the $x$ axis until its center is at $A'.$
If the circle had slid along the $x$ axis instead of rolling,
the dot would now be at $Q,$ directly below $A'.$
But because of the rolling, the circle rotated clockwise and now the dot is at $P'$
with $\angle QA'P' = t/2$ (measured in radians).

Note that $A'R = \cos(t/2)$ (the difference in $y$ coordinates between $A'$ and $P'$)
and $P'R = \sin(t/2)$ (the difference in $x$ coordinates).
In the figure as shown both $\cos(t/2)$ and $\sin(t/2)$ are positive.
But because we go downward from $A'$ to $R$ and leftward from $R$ to $P',$
we need to add *negative* values to the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of $A'$
in order to arrive at the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of $P'.$
Specifically, we need the coordinates of the vector between these points to be $\vec{A'P'} =  \langle -\sin(t/2), -\cos(t/2) \rangle.$

In short, when the angle $t/2$ is acute (and therefore both its sine and cosine are positive), the vector $\vec{A'P'}$ points *downward* and to the *left*, so it requires both coordinates to be negative. To get negative numbers from positive numbers you need to apply a $-$ sign.

---

It is not clear why you assume that $P$ should have coordinates
$(\sin(1/t),\cos(1/t))$. (Surely, to start with, you meant $t/2$ rather than $1/t$.)

The points on a unit circle with center at $(0,0)$ (not $(0,2)$) are often described as having coordinates $(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$ (note that the cosine comes first!),
but that's assuming that we start with the point $(1,0)$
(directly to the right of the circle's center) when $\theta = 0$
and proceed counterclockwise around the circle.
In this problem the motion around the center of the circle is quite different:
we start below the center and move in a clockwise direction.

Since the starting point (when $\theta = 0$) and direction of rotation (as $\theta$ increases) are different from the usual unit-circle arrangement, we have to work out the coordinates from first principles.

---

By the way, if the solution had said, "as can be seen in **the** sketch," I would expect to see a sketch.
But instead it says, "as can be seen in **a** sketch," which is something people may write when they are inviting the readers to draw their own sketches.
Drawing a sketch like the one above and inserting it in an on-line document (like the problem set, or like this answer) is a lot more effort than doodling one on a piece of scrap paper, so perhaps we can forgive the authors of open courseware from putting the burden on the students to make those doodles.
It's true, however, that a picture is worth a lot of words of explanation,
so I made the effort to upload one.

Comment: Thank you very much. Physics is not my initial interest but I’m trying to understand the course to the deepest level as I can understand. Before I’ve reached these parametric equations everything has being a breeze but they are just really tough and made me contemplate my existence.

Answer (score 0):

At time $t$ the centre of the disc has moved a distance $t$.

Let the point on the circumference of the disc which coincided with the origin at time $t=0$ be labelled $Q$.

Let the point of contact of the disc and the horizontal surface at time $t$ be labelled $R$.

Because the disc has rolled without slipping, the arc $QR$ has length $t$.

If the angle subtended by this arc at the centre of the disc is $\theta$, then, since the radius of the disc is $2$, we have $$t=2\theta$$

Therefore, relative to the centre of the disc, the point $P$ has coordinates $$(-\sin\theta, -\cos\theta)=(-\sin\frac12t, -\cos\frac12t)$$

Vector addition then gives the position vector $\overrightarrow{OP}$ as described.

I hope this helps.

Comment: can you please provide me with a graph of this?

Comment: the place where I'm confused is about the minus sign. The points on the circumference should be given as $(2\sin(1/t),2\cos(1/t))$ and since the point $P$ lies in the middle, it should be $P(\sin(1/t),\cos(1/t))$ but why the minus?